# count red color object from video opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm trying to count how many red color bar from this video

[tes1.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxZMPpHTwlpLbXZGdVBMVGpnQXFHb05HbEVfZnlqcm52YllV)

and this is my function to count the object by count the center of the object

```
def count(frame):
frame = imutils.resize(frame,640,480)
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask=cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1)
center=[]

for i in range(len(contours)):
    c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    if M["m00"]==0:
        M["m00"]=0.6
    cx=int (M["m10"]/M["m00"])
    cy=int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    print "center",len(center)

    center.append((cx,cy))
    cv2.circle(frame, center[-1],3,(0,0,0),-1)
```

but the problem is len(center) appear more than 300. can anyone help to count how many the red bar. any solution will be helpful.

Comment: Can you update the values for lower and upper and may be add the mask you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I made it: first, subtract blue and green channels from the red channel to find the "red" pixels. The result looks like this:

[image]

Threshold works really well on this, obviously:

[image]

From here we can find contours:

[image]

Count them, and that's the number of stripes. But there's also `connectedComponents` function, it can count those without finding contours.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#load a frame as int16 array to avoid overflow etc. when subtracting
img = cv2.imread("test_images/redbars.png").astype(np.int16)

#separating into blue, green and red channels
img_b = img[:, :, 0]
img_g = img[:, :, 1]
img_r = img[:, :, 2]

#for a red stripe, the red component should be much bigger than the rest
res_br = img_r - img_b
res_gr = img_r - img_g
res = np.maximum(res_br, res_gr)
res[res < 0] = 0
res = res.astype(np.uint8)  #convert back to uint8 for findContours etc.

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(res, 50, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#find contours and count them
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#gives the correct output of 5
print(len(contours))

#alternatively, count connected components with this:
ncomp, nimg = cv2.connectedComponents(thresh)
print(ncomp - 1)  #it counts the background as one of the components, so subtract 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pipeline you can use to *count the number of red strips* on a frame:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat input = imread("red_lines.png");
    Mat hsv;
    cvtColor(input, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

    Mat mask;
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, 0,0), Scalar(15, 255,255), mask);

    Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(7, 7));
    erode(mask, mask, kernel);
    dilate(mask, mask, kernel);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(mask, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    cout << "objects found: " << contours.size() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        drawContours(input, contours, i, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    }

    imshow("mask", mask);
    imshow("contours", input);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The important part in my code, is the **[morphological operations](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html)** ([erosion](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb) then [dilation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga4ff0f3318642c4f469d0e11f242f3b6c)) I apply on the mask (resulting from `inRange`). This allows to remove the "*mask's noise*" and thus to catch only the big red strips.

[image: Red strips with a green outline]

To further improve the robustness, I recommend you to check the *area* of each contour. If it is above a certain *threshold*, just discard it.

P.S. This is C++ code, but I'm sure you'll figure out how to translate it into Python code... :)